# Why does rails 3 show "(/)" when I use the link_to img_tag helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

here's the code:

```
    <%= link_to tag("img", { :src => "/images/logo.png", :alt => "logo"}, false), {:controller => 'frontpage', :action => 'index'}, :class => "logo" %>
```

the output:
[image]

'(/)'

the '(/)' --minus the quotes, come at the end of the image

Comment: Why aren't you using the image_tag helper, just out of interest?

Comment: I started out using image_tag, but got the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have that floating in your HTML somewhere?

Also, you're doing a lot more work than necessary:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('logo.png'), frontpages_path, :class => 'logo' %>
```

That'll automatically assign "Logo" as the alt text, and assuming you're using RESTful routes, that `frontpages_path` helper will already exist.

Comment: I copied the code and still got the same problem.  '(frontpages)' at the end of the image.

Comment: I figured it out.  It was a css conflict with blueprint css.  I took out stylesheet_link_tag and the '()' went away.  thanks for your help (I'm using the code you suggested above).